# ¿Como puedo devolver algo en el constructor para utilizarlo en mi clase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un filtro de acción para hacer un log en una clase llamada `LogActionFilter` el cual tiene sus respectivos metodos para realziar cada tarea especifica, y desde mi controlado llamo a este filtro de la siguiente forma `[LogActionFilter]` hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es que necesito pasar un mensaje personalizado hacia la clase del filtro de acción estilo: `[LogActionFilter("Mi mensaje de log")]` para que lo reciba mi clase y poder utilizarlo en los demás métodos de ella.

Se que debo utilizar un constructor para ello, pero no se como recuperar el dato para utilizar en mis demás métodos que están fuera del constructor.

Mi Clase o Filtro de Acción:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute{
    public LogActionFilter(string msg){

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
        Log("OnActionExecuting Firxt", filterContext.RouteData);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext){
        Log("OnActionExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext){
        Log("OnResultExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext){
        Log("OnResultExecuted", filterContext.RouteData);
    }

    private void Log(string v, RouteData routeData){
        var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = routeData.Values["action"];
        var message = String.Format("{0} controller:{1} action:{2}", v, controllerName, actionName);
        Debug.WriteLine(message, "Action Filter Log");
    }
}
```

Mi Controller:

```
[LogActionFilter("SUCCES")]
public class HomeController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About(){
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact(){
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Los constuctores no pueden devolver ningún valor (son métodos especiales para crear instancias de clases), igual si quieres obtener algo puedes ponerle un parámetro de salida, pero no te es mejor almacenarlo en una propiedad??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma, no se si sera "correcta".

Mi constructor:

```
private string message;

public LogActionFilter()
{
}

public LogActionFilter(string msg)
{
    this.message = msg;
}

public string Message
{
    get => message;
    set => message = value;
}
```

Pero al inspeccionar lo que contiene el parámetro `msg` me indica ERROR, eso no se por que sucede... pero funciona bien.

Comment: Felicidades, haz aprendido a utilizar propiedades, 
las propiedades son una manera de exponer variables de la clase. 

por que message te da error? ni idea, tal vez tengas un problema con tu depurador.. aunque.... tienes tanto get/set asi que no hay diferencia entre el public Message y el private message...  

yo nunca le he encontrado el sentido a exponer completamente la variable privada con propiedades publicas... mejor hago la variable publica y me olvido de las propiedades

Comment: Si el mensaje con el que inicializas la clade atributo no necesitas modificarlo una vez instanciado, ¿porqué no lo haces de solo lectura? es preferible declarar la propiedad asi: public string Message  { get; } quitas el campo message y en el constructor , en vez de "this.message = msg;" pones "this.Message = msg;" de esa forma: 1) te quitas el campo y ahorras un par de líneas, 2) realmente encapsulas tu estado, es mas seguro y es lo que mas se recomienda. Entre menos setters tengas, mejor. O si  necesitas modificar el mensaje quita el field y deja la propiedad Message con {get;set}